# Dynamically modify location background updates in Swift

Tags: swift

I am developing an iOS app that uses the users location and stores their paths. I have everything working except after I request the users permission to use their location when using the app and when background updates are enabled, I can't seem to stop location updates at all unless I force quit the app.

What I would like to achieve is when the user first starts the app I get their location and change the camera position. Then if the user presses a start button background location updates are enabled however if they put the app in to the background without pressing the start location updates are not tracked.

I am println both the start and the end but I still need to quit the app to stop location updates.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0;
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true
        viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true
        println("Location updated and started")
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {

        viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 60)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        println("Location updated and stopped")
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller, register for notification UIApplicationDidEnterBackground and when that happens check whether user has pressed the start button (store the state value in a variable), if not then access the location manager object and call stopUpdatingLocation.

Comment: Thanks but not sure if this is working. If I register for background updates, regardless of whether I have started or stopped location updates, I still get the blue bar at the top of the app when the app is in the background.

Comment: In addition to the previous answer, your problem might be that you don't use the same locationManager, try to make it a static and call the same in both your app delegate and your map class.